# How to Push Local Notification in android at some particular time when device is in sleep mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, notifications

Actually I am trying to make my college routine app..which notifies the current period to the user using NotificationManager(i have total nine periods and some are at different time intervals)...its all working fine, but the problem occurs when device goes to sleep, it doesn't  push any notification in sleep mode...I am using a service to push notification but i guess service also goes to sleep during sleep mode...My service is never killed automatically during sleep...but it doesn't give any notification... Please Help me

[Click Here to view my code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xNHvCfaTStNkwxcnJOMmZZa2M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Add this in *AndroidManifest.xml*         `    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Comment: thaat eats up too much battery

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar issue but in my case this behavior is random. I am getting the notification in sleep mode for some time and after few minutes or so the notification just stops. On press of lock button, it again starts. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

i do this with broadcastreceivers I set a repeating broadcast every 60 seconds

like this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,thebroadcastclass.class);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HIGH");
        broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),60000, broadcast);
```

It works fine but the interval must be at least 60 seconds
(It would drain the battery too much)

this is the broadcastreceiver:

```
public class thebroadcastclass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        toastmaker.update(context, intent);
    }}
```

I hope you can use this(: